# Laravel: Access denied for user 'newuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `roles`)

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

i want to run my project with root user. but when i run my project,

i am getting error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'newuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `roles`)

in Connection.php line 647
```

**.env:**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=course
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

i want to use root `with all privileges and no password`, then why i am getting error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'newuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `roles`)
```

**MySql:**

[image]

Comment: it looks to be a cache problem try to run this command `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: @Joseph it will delete .env file (:

Comment: make sure You don't have duplicate `DB_USERNAME` and `DB_PASSWORD` in `.env` file

Comment: @num8er I don't think that it clear the cache of config files only

Comment: i was running this command to clear cache it didn't work, but now it did work. wow

Comment: @Joseph my friend once run config:clear and could not find .env file (:

Comment: i run it in my localhost and everything is fine for me and nothing deleted as you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to clear your `config` cache files by running this `command`

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 2):

clear config cache

```
php artisan config:clear
```